# What's the meaning of "off to an early start" in this context?

Tags: phrases

The context as below:

> but violent clashes between riot police and students at the end of September got the action off to an early start

Comment: A start that was early. What difficulty are you having with understanding the normal dictionary definitions as used here?

Comment: The action started early.  It's that simple.

Comment: In context, it's a "flippant" usage. Usually only things like *football matches* would be referenced in this way. But as @Jon implies, the meaning is General Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "off" is probably what makes the idiom not completely simple. It actually doesn't change the meaning very much - it's just part of the phrase "got off to an early start."

The following sentence means the same thing as yours:

> Violent clashes between riot police and students at the end of September were an early start to the action.